# What is a "nonreactive" pan?

Tags: equipment, sauce

I just realized the recipe I use for Chardonnay Beurre Blanc requires the use of a "small nonreactive saucepan."

In the past, I have used my 1.5 quart All-Clad saucepan without problems.

What sort of pan materials should I avoid?

Similarly, I've seen recipes indicate one should use a nonreactive bowl. I typically use plastic in those cases. Should I be using something different?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try cooking tomato sauce in a cast-iron pan some time... You'll learn a whole new meaning for "irony".

A non-reactive pan is one that allows you to cook or store acidic foods without dissolving, leaching, or otherwise causing contamination. Good materials for such pans include glass, stainless steel, food-grade plastic, ceramic, porcelain, and *hard anodized* aluminum. Bad materials include cast-iron, copper, and aluminum.

Plastic bowls should be fine for most purposes, *however* keep in mind that small scratches in the plastic may harbor contaminants that will be freed by the acid. So clean them well, or switch to glass.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by “try cooking tomato sauce in cast iron”?  I cook shakshuka in cast iron often and have not had any troubles.

Comment: Short cook time in a well-seasoned pan will probably not do anything harmful, @dpollitt. Long cook times are another story: if the acid makes it through the seasoning, the flavor will be ruined. America's Test Kitchen found the flavor noticeable [after 30 minutes](https://www.americastestkitchen.com/guides/cook-it-in-cast-iron/busting-cast-iron-myths#the-myth-you-cant-cook-wine-tomatoes-or-other-acidic-ingredients-in-a-cast-iron-pan) - this will vary with pan and acidity, but if you're planning a multi-hour simmer, a non-reactive pan will be needed.

Answer (score 4):

Non-reactive means stainless steel or ceramic-lined; not copper, cast-iron, or aluminum which tend to react with acidic foods in particular. Glass is non-reactive as well (for bowls).

Comment: I would add aluminum as one to avoid as well. And as for non-reactive bowls, I would use glass.

Comment: Quite right, editing my answer.

Comment: PTFE nonstick would probably be considered nonreactive as well...